# VPN Connection shows error 720 in Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, ethernet

I'm working in a company with a local network and Internet is shared using VPN connections. I'm connecting to the network with my laptop.

Yesterday I did a Network Reset and after that I cannot connect to the VPN Server and The network support couldn't find the solution.
I did another Network reset, disabled Comodo Firewall and the problem still exists.

This is the error:

> Can't connect to {Connection Name} A connection to the remote computer
>   could not be established. You might need to change the network
>   settings for this connection

[image]

**Other Info:**

- All computers are connecting to the network using Ethernet connections
- This connection is working perfectly on other computers.
- My LAN setting is set to DHCP and all other settings are as default
- I can access other network resources like shared folders
- I found out that user authentication is getting done successfully. Because when I try to connect with wrong credentials, user validation error occurs.
- I could not find anything related in Windows Log Viewer

These are my connection properties:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is your computer/user account allowed to remote dial-in? In AD Users and Computers your user account should have a "dial in" tab.

Comment: @Kinnectus Where is AD Users and Computers? In my laptop or the server? I could not find it on my laptop.

Comment: It'll be on the server if you haven't got RSAT installed. Although, and I missed this, you've siad it has worked before you "reset" the network adapter on your laptop...

Comment: Yes, it was working before.

Comment: How can I diagnose the connection? Can I run connecting process step by step?

Comment: Unfortuantely you can't. I would suggest you re-create the VPN connection as a new adapter (just give it a different name). make sure the settings are all the same and then try to connect. I've seen issues in the past where re-creating the adapter fixes the issue (or, at least, rules this out).

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and it was fixed by following this procedure:

1. Open Device Manager (Right Click on Start button and choose device manager)
2. Expand the 'Network Adapters'
   [WAN miniports in device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAmCT.png)
3. Uninstall all all WAN Miniport adapters
4. Reboot

!!!PROBLEM SOLVED!!!

Comment: Rebooting is not "solving" the problem--it is re-baselining the entire OS. A less rash solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Defintely solves the problem. The OP's question describes exactly what I found at a client site. See also the earlier question (for windows 8 to 8.1) with the same error at https://superuser.com/questions/525602/all-created-vpns-result-in-error-720  The solution worked perfectly, and of course, after removing all the broken wan miniports, *of course* windows will need a reboot. StackExchange FTW!